# Simple way to get parameter from URL and place it into an input control?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url, parameters, input

I'm making an invite system where a user when registering to the site can specify a user who refereed them.

There's also a way for existing users to send invites. The friend would recieve a link:

```
http://www.foo.com/account/register?referal=sandyUser216
```

How can I get that value `sandyUser216` and place it as the value inside of a text input box?

I'm using C# and MVC3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `Request.QueryString`.

```
<input type="text" value="@Request.QueryString["referal"]" />
```

Or put it in a Model property rather than having it in the view.

Answer (score 1):

As **always** in an ASP.NET MVC application you start by writing a view model that will represent the information contained in your view:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Referal { get; set; }
}
```

then you write controller actions for respectively showing the registration form and processing it:

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Register")]
public ActionResult ProcessRegistration(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    // TODO: perform the registration
    return RedirectToAction("success");
}
```

and finally you write the corresponding strongly typed view:

```
@model RegisterViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Referal)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Referal)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Referal)
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
}
```

Now all that's left is to simply navigate to `/account/register?referal=sandyUser216`.

And you have accomplished the whole MVC pattern. Should you skip any of those 3 letters it means that you are doing ASP.NET MVC incorrectly.

Comment: What happens if the user goes directly to the registration form without clicking a referral email?

Comment: @Sergio Tapia, you could check whether the model is valid inside the Register GET action: `if (!ModelState.IsValid) { ... }`. If the modelstate is not valid you will know that the Referal property of your view model was not passed and you could take respective actions like for example throwing a 403 Unauthorized or 404 Not Found depending on your requirements of course.

Comment: When visiting the URL the parameter isn't being filled in. What should I check?

Comment: That you are passing it in the query string `/account/register?referal=sandyUser216` and that you haven't made some stupid typo when naming the property in your view model and somehow it is different than the name of the query string parameter.

Comment: Those are the first things I checked. Maybe it's because I'm using EditorFor?

Comment: Yep, tried typing in many different query strings for the other fields and none of them work. I think the theory is sound but the code itself doesn't place the value into the input. Any alternatives? Did you test this code?

Comment: I absolutely tested this code and it worked perfectly fine. I always test code before posting on StackOverflow. So if you want you could send me a narrowed down version of your project illustrating the problem and I will tell you what's wrong.